# Kubuntu 15.04 lock screen delayed after waking up

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, 15.04, power-management

How to get rid of this?

When I close the laptop lid, it suspends. But then, I open it, hit the power button to resume it, and I see my desktop (wow much secure). It is unresponsive, I can't click anywhere. After a while (over 10-15 seconds) the lock screen appears and I can type a password to unlock it.